# Hide/show div on hover of dropdown selection options

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$('#dropdown-list').on('change',function(){
  if( $(this).val()==="option 1" ){
    $("#diva").hide()
  } else {
    $("#divb").show()
  }
});
```

I am using the above to hide/show a div when a dropdown selection is selected, that works. Now I need to enhance this. I want to hide/show a div while hovering the dropdown options. Is that an option as well?

Comment: Consider using CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a css class

```
hide {
 display: none;
}
```

Then add a hover event on your element :

```
$('#dropdown-option').on('hover', function(e) {
  // Add class to your element or other div with .addClass(className) or .removeClass(className) 
});
```

OR (it depend the behavior your really need)

```
$('#div').on('mouseover', function(e) {
  // Add class to your element or other div
});
```

You should test both.

You can also use directly .hover() from jQuery https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score -1):

If you have many options, your code will become a nightmare. I recommend using `data-` attributes and `options` within a select.

```js
$('#mySelectOptions').on('mouseover', function () {
    //  E.g. allows you to get/set the selected Id
    var idSelectedOption = $(this).children('option:selected').data("idresult");
    // Show the div for the selected Option, & Hide the other siblings, or add/any more class names for desired purpose.
    $('#'+idSelectedOption).show().siblings('div').hide(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelectOptions">
 <option data-idresult="1" value="Value test 1">TEST 1</option>
 <option data-idresult="2"  value="Value test 2">TEST 2</option>
 <option data-idresult="3"  value="Value test 3">TEST 3</option>
</select>

<div id="1" style="display:none;">Div value for idresult=1</div>
<div id="2" style="display:none;">Div value for idresult=2</div>
<div id="3" style="display:none;">Div value for idresult=3</div>
```

Comment: I already have it working when selected. I am looking for a toggle while hovering the options.